# compression buckling of frame

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

all. The top beam is subjected to uniformly distributed load. FYI, the column is 5m in length.  As you can see, the major axis of column is connected to the beam with moment connection on top. However, in the minor axis of column, there's nothing to connecting them.

For the major axis, the buckling length shall be 0.7*5 = 3.5m (K = 0.7 for bottom pinned, top fixed condition) ,

For the minor axis , the buckling length shall be 2*5 = 10m , right ?? (because in minor axis, it's cantilever , nothing to restrain the column on top) . However, the program detect the buckling length as 5.0m.

So, my question, for the minor axis, is it considered as cantilever ? Or since  in the major axis, it's already gt the moment connection, in minor axis of connection, there's really doesn't matter whether the minor axis of column in restrained or not...

[image: 11]

[image: 22]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you modelled the structure in 3D structural analysis program, for such a case, if the two frames are pinned at the base of columns, but not connected on the top (two independent frames), the program shall issue a warning, because the frames are unstable in the transverse direction (pinned at the bottom, free on the top). You need to check your inputs for mistakes.

Comment: Do you mean by right, for the minor axis of column, there must be something to restrain on top also , otherwise it's unstable ? because in minor axis direction, the bottom is pinned, the top is free in the situation above, the frame is unstable ?

Comment: Can I say that since the frame is moment connection in the major axis of column, so the column would buckle in the direction of major axis of column only, and in the major axis of column is already properly braced, the column wouldnt buckle in the minor axis ? It's fine to not to brace the top part of the column in the minor axis (pinned, free) ??

Comment: No, the column design is controlled by the minor axis, which has the least of radius of gyration. You need at least two horizontal members on top to connect the two frames to make it a stable structure (like a table), and if the members are simply connected to the column, then the effective length in direction on the minor axis is equal to 5.0 m (since K = 1 for pin-pin supported column).

Comment: If you do not wish to provide upper members, then you would have two independent frames (why?), in such case, you have to make the columns fixed at the base, so in direction of the minor axis, you would have fixed-free (cantilever) support conditions.

Comment: So, can I say that when the axial load is applied to the column, it will surely buckle in 2 directions ( major and minor axes direction) ? The minor axis which has the radius of gyration, which will govern the column design ?? (My previous statement of column will only buckle in the major axis direction (since the major axis of column  is properly connected to column)  is wrong  ?? )

Comment: If I wish not to provide the top members at the minor axis direction, just provide fixed base , will do ? If i provide fixed base , the major axis direction of column will become fixed, fixed, in minor axis direction, it will become fixed, free ? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: As said above, the minor axis has the least radius of gyration, so in direction of the minor axis, it is the weak plane of the column, that is prone to sway and buckle. It would help to review the derivation of allowable compressive stress of the compression member (column), the equation involves the term - slenderness ratio, "KL/r", and the larger the ratio, the smaller the allowable stress, that is the controlling factor for column design.

Comment: So, no matter whether the connection between column and beam in major direction is fixed or not, in the minor axis direction of column, it must be restrained on top (if the fixed is pinned ) ? if it's pinned base, the top of minor axis of column, can be cantilever (the worst case , k= 2.0) ? Am i right ??

Comment: Yes, if you do not want to add members to the top, then you must keep the column base fixed, so in direction of the major axis (framing plane), the columns are fixed-fixed, and in direction of the minor axis, the columns are fixed-free.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is just a single frame example.. Say that if I have a multi bay frame, is it necessary to provide cross bracing or top horizontal member to restrain the minor axis of column ? Or just provide the top horizontal member / cross bracing at the end bay will do ? Don't need to provide bracing/ horizontal member at every bay ??

Comment: Btw, cross bracing and the top horizontal member serves the same purpose, right ?

Comment: If it is a single portal frame, you need the keep the column base fixed, so in direction of the minor axis, the entire frame is a cantilever. If the column base is pinned without transverse support on top, it will rotate about the major axis of the column (due to the lack of rotational restrain at the base), thus it is unstable.

Comment: For structure with multiple frames, yes, you would need bracings to maintain the squareness of the frames in relation to each other. Bracing design involves many factors, such as loads, building/structure geometry...etc. You should open another query with plan of interest to get responses. Hope I didn't confuse you. Good luck.  But note, the horizontal cross bracing can't be consider a substitute of the transverse horizontal member for column design, as it does not provide reliable support in direction of the column minor axis.

Comment: Just wondering whether the cross bracing can substitute the horizontal top member to restrain the minor axis buckling of column or not. If there's already cross bracing in place, can we just remove the top horizontal bracing member at the top for pinned base? (I am asking for minor axis buckling of column now)

Comment: But, why the cross bracing can't be consider substitute of the horizontal top member to restrain minor axis buckling of column? I think cross bracing also act as same way as horizontal member on top to restrain minor axis buckling of column, right?

Comment: Unlike cross bracing in the vertical plane, without the horizontal transverse member between columns/frames, the horizontal cross bracing can't form a completely enclosed triangle ( that is the most stable shape), as a consequence, the braces can undergo lateral movement freely (image a pair of scissors), thus it is unreliable. It surely offers some help than nothing, but the effectiveness is very difficult to evaluate.